# NotificationCenter - addObserver not called

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

I am trying a very simple code with NotificationCenter. But the addObserver is not getting called. Can any one of you check and let me know what i am missing. There are 2 simple class, one which post notification and another which listens to it. When i run the program, i just see "sending notification" in the console.

Thanks in advance.

Class 1:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("sending notification")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("test"), object: nil)
    }
}
```

Class 2:

```
class secondvc: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("second vc")
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
            selector: #selector(doThisWhenNotify(_:)),
            name: Notification.Name("test"),
            object: nil)
    }
     
    @objc  func doThisWhenNotify(_ notification: Notification) {
         print("inside notification")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you not see "second vc" printed out either? If that's the case, you're never initializing your secondvc so its viewDidLoad() isn't being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, at the time `ViewController` comes into existence, `secondvc` does not yet exist, then there is no one there to receive the posted notification and that is why you don't see the notification being received later when `secondvc` *does* come into existence.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Got it now... will work on it accordingly.